# Azure DevOps YAML - Problem with multiple pipelines per version/branch conception

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Simplifying my current scenario is that I have repo with two branches "develop" and "release". There is `azure-pipeline.yml` file and two pipelines attached to it (one per branch). In `develop` I have:

```
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - develop
```

and in `release` is:

```
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - release
```

When I commit changes to only one of this branches two pipelines are triggered - why? What I missing here?

Should I exclude oposit branch (or more branches in future) or maybe have two sepearate files `azure-pipeline-develop.yml` and `azure-pipeline-release.yml`?

What is general conception to have builds per app version? When for example I would like still build old release because of patching?

What option is easier to maintain?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you have one `azure-pipeline.yml` file, and **two** pipelines in Azure DevOps, each using the same file.

Since both pipelines in Azure DevOps are using the same yaml file, each pipeline is evaluating the triggers across all branches on every push from every branch.

The pipeline you expect to be a "release" pipeline doesn't know that its not supposed to run "develop" builds.

As you mentioned, one of the ways to resolve this would be to create two yaml files, one per pipeline, however I think there's a better way.

**Build all branches from the same pipeline.**

Azure DevOps is designed to build multiple branches from the same pipeline. If you want to build a `/release` branch you can build it in the same pipeline that builds `/develop` branch. Docs and tutorials here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/ci-build-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Yes I have one `yml` file but when I was creating 2nd pipeline I selected this file from another branch where this file is little diffrent (ex. triggers).